# Compare two files in Hadoop MapReduce

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

Hi I'm pretty new to Hadoop and mapreduce..I'm wondering if something like this is possible.
I'm trying to compare two files through Mapreduce..
The first file may look something like this:

```
t1 r1
t2 r2
t1 r4
```

The second file will look something like this:

```
u1 t1 r1
u2 t2 r3
u3 t2 r2
u4 t1 r1
```

I want it to emit `u1`, `u3` and `u4` based on the files. The second file will be considerably larger than the first file. I'm not too sure how to compare these files; is this doable in one MapReduce job? I'm willing to chain MapReduce jobs if I have to though.

Comment: How big are these files that you want to use MapReduce?

Comment: The second file is at least 1GB. The first file is actually the result of a MapReduce on the second file given, for example all lines that started with `u1`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could do a [mapside](https://gist.github.com/airawat/6587341) join by placing 1st file in distributed cache and traversing the second file in map phase to do a join.

How to read from distributed cache:

```
@Override
        protected void setup(Context context) throws IOException,InterruptedException
        {
            Path[] filelist=DistributedCache.getLocalCacheFiles(context.getConfiguration());
            for(Path findlist:filelist)
            {
                if(findlist.getName().toString().trim().equals("mapmainfile.dat"))
                {

                    fetchvalue(findlist,context);
                }
            }

        }
        public void fetchvalue(Path realfile,Context context) throws NumberFormatException, IOException
        {
            BufferedReader buff=new BufferedReader(new FileReader(realfile.toString()));
           //some operations with the file
        }
```

How to add a file to distributed cache:

```
DistributedCache.addCacheFile(new URI("/user/hduser`/test/mapmainfile.dat"),conf);`
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mapper side join for comparison. Use distributed cache to pass smaller file to all the mappers and read larger file record by record through the mapper.

Now you can easily compare the large file record received against the small file (from distributed cache) and emit records which match.

Note: This will work only when the first file is sufficiently small to fit in the memory of the mapper. Generally an catalog file or a look up file

Answer (score 0):

You can use reduce side join if both files are large, for that:

1. Create two mappers for each of these two files using MultipleInput format. so one input file going to one mapper, another file to another mapper.
2. Send first mappers output data with a key as composit key (TextPair). first part in the pair is like "t1 r1", "t1, r2" etc and 2nd part is "0" from first mapper, and "1" from 2nd mapper. For values, emit nullWritable from first mapper and u1, u2 etc from 2nd. So ouptput from first mapper will be such as (("t1 r1", "0"),null), and 2nd  mapper output as (("t1 r1", 1), u1), (("t1 r1", 1"), u4) etc using "0" from first mapper, so that first mapper ouput is received first.
3. Implement partitioner and group comparator based on first part of TextPair key.
4. In the reducer you would get data grouped by first part  and recive it  like this - [("t1 r1", 0"), null), (("t1 r1", 1"), u1), (("t1 r1", 1"), u4) ]
5. Discard all the inputs which doesn't fist key with "0" (so it will remove unmatched entries) and emit rest of the values u1, u4 etc.